# I have multiple buttons and when the users clicks on a button I want the button to have a certain background color. How do I achieve this in react?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have the clicked button to remain selected even if I move to next step/page and come back to the initial page of the form where I selected the button. I'm not sure how to execute that. I am just starting to learn React - Thank you.

My Css for selected btn

```
 button:active, button:focus {
            background-color: blue;
            color: #FFFFFF;
      }
```

At the moment I have saved the selected button on state as below,

```
patientLocation = e => {
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
        this.setState ( { patientLocation: e.target.value, selectedBtn: e.currentTarget } );
    }
```

My Buttons on render

````
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Bedroom"> Bedroom </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="TV lounge"> TV lounge </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Corridor"> Corridor </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Bathroom / Shower"> Bathroom / Shower </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Reading room"> Reading room</button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Activity Room"> Activity Room</button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Garden"> Garden </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Toilet"> Toilet </button>     
                                    <button type="button"  onClick={this.props.patientLocation} value="Load more options"> Load more options </button>     
</div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 (similar) solutions.
First, save the selected button in the state of parent component and pass in as props. You can pass through props function that changes parents state.

Or you can use some global state, like redux.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a className only to the currently selected button, and then use that className to style it.

```
<button 
   id="bedroom-btn" // better to use an id to identify which button is selected
   type="button" 
   className={this.props.selectedBtn === "bedroom-btn" ? "activeBtn" : ""}  // <-- like this
   onClick={this.props.patientLocation} 
   value="Bedroom"
>
   Bedroom 
</button>
```

then in css

```
button.activeBtn {
   background-color: blue;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

and your handle function becomes

```
patientLocation = e => {
        this.setState ( { patientLocation: e.target.value, selectedBtn: e.target.id } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` with `reactjs` for `DOM manipulation` like adding and removing class. This is the working solution of your question.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedBtnId: "",
    patientLocation: ""
  };
  btnArray = [
    { location: "Bedroom", id: "btnFirst" },
    { location: "TV lounge", id: "btnSecond" },
    { location: "Corridor", id: "btnThird" },
    { location: "Bathroom / Shower", id: "btnFourth" },
    { location: "Reading room", id: "btnFifth" },
    { location: "Activity Room", id: "btnSixth" },
    { location: "Garden", id: "btnSeventh" },
    { location: "Toilet", id: "btnEighth" },
    { location: "Load more options", id: "btnNineth" }
  ];
  clickHandler = (event, id, location) => {
    this.btnArray.forEach(btn => {
      jQuery("#" + btn.id).removeClass("selected");
    });
    let selectedBtnId = id === this.state.selectedBtnId ? "" : id;
    let patientLocation =
      location === this.state.patientLocation ? "" : location;
    if (selectedBtnId !== "") jQuery("#" + selectedBtnId).addClass("selected");
    this.setState({ selectedBtnId, patientLocation });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-class">
       {this.state.patientLocation ? (
          <h3> Patient Location {this.state.patientLocation}</h3>
        ) : null}
        {this.btnArray.map((btn, index) => (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={event => this.clickHandler(event, btn.id, btn.location)}
            key={btn.id}
            id={btn.id}
            className="btn"
          >
            {btn.location}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.selected {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-class .btn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```